# What anime is this brown uniform with a yellow-white ribbon from?

Tags: cosplay

[image: Costume from Bodyline]

I found this costume on the Bodyline website. I want to know what it's from and what character wears it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is without a doubt the National Verbena Academy's winter uniform (from the *Shuffle* anime, with some minor inaccuracies).

[image: Watch out! It's Kaede!]